# How to concatenate duplicated values from a muti column / row array in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, join, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to get a value in a single cell which looks at a 2 row and multi-column array and finds the values that are the same between the 2 rows

I'm pretty sure that an `INDEX` / `MATCH` function should do the job however there's no combination that I've been able to find that adequately achieves the result

A working example can be summarised as such:

The array looks like this:-

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE | ColF  
Row1 | Dogs | Cats | Mice | Frog | Goat  
Row2 | Mice | Frog
```

The function needs to look at all the values in Row 1 and compare them to all the values in Row 2, find the matching ones and output them (with a delimiter) in another cell
The desired output is "Mice-Frog"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN("-", 1, 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(1:1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 2:2)))))
```

[image: 0]

---

or already mentioned:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("-", HLOOKUP(INDIRECT("A2:"&ADDRESS(2, COUNTA(2:2))), 1:1, 1, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this:

```
=join("-",ARRAYFORMULA(hlookup(A2:B2,A1:E1,1,0)))
```